# Help me create formula for such sequence

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

:)

I'm web-developer, and currently I'm looking for formula to automate "discount" percent discovery.

Our old formula is `min(10, 5 + ordersDone)`, which generally gives 5..10% discount for first 5 orders and 10% for 6th+

And now, we're going to change this to:

```
ordersDone    discount%
       0-1    1%
       2-3    2%
       4-6    3%
      7-10    4%
     11-15    5%
     16-21    6%
     22-28    7%
     29-36    8%
     37-45    9%
     45-55    10%
       56+    10%
```

For 2-55 sequences, i found that amount of orders is equal to discount, like: `7, 8, 9, 10 == 4`

But i'm totally without idea how to find formula for this without cycles(for/loop/while & etc.)

Comment: Look-up table? Modern languages have hash tables, it's not too slow. You could also ask this on stackoverflow, with precision on the language you use.

Comment: Generally, i'm trying to evade loops/hashes/tables ;)

Comment: But sometimes a formula does not speed things up (compare for example solution of fourth degree polynomial with Ferrari's method vs Newton iteration). And it's much more difficult to generalize, in your case (e.g. if you change anything in discount pattern).

Comment: @arbautjc Ours not to reason why; ours but to find a formula.

Comment: I don't quite agree. I'm here to help solve problems. Whole problems. Just answering a question without thinking about other/better approaches is not particularly wise. Especially when dealing with computer programs. And I insist, when programming, maintainability/readability is much more important than speed, when speed gain is not likely to be huge.

Comment: Oh don't worry, i'm pretty experienced developer and can solve this with different ways, but somehow i want get advanced in math :) That's why i do such small things with formula :)

Yeah, and i'm planning on getting math lessons :)

Comment: Oh, that's different then ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are interested in the triangular numbers $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...$

The formula for this is given by $$t_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

The inverse of this function is:

$$ n = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1 + 8 t_n} - 1 \right) $$

Use this inverse and round up to find what value your discount should be

Edit:  You can represent the final equation mathematically by

$$ \text{discount} = \min \left \{10, \left \lceil \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1 + 8 \cdot \text{#orders}} - 1 \right) \right \rceil \right \} $$

where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly :)
I'll accept answer in 5 minutes, waiting for delay ;)

Comment: Np.  You might want to tweak the formula so that it gives a 1% discount to those who have 0 orders :)

Comment: Already noticed it and fixed ;) Btw which math's division covers all this formula reverse engineering?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's any particular subject, it's more general experience.  In this case the numbers your cut-offs were a sequence familiar to me and inverting it was algebra.